# TransactionScope, Selects using Subsonic

Tags: subsonic

I have an Invoice table (and a SubSonic 'Invoice' `ActiveRecord()` with an `InvoiceNumebr` column that needs to have unique numbers. I am trying to `GetTheNextAvailableNumber()` inside of a `TransactionScope` using block. This works.

What I'm not sure of is, what happens if 5, or 50 different users try to create an Invoice at approx. the same time, the method would return the same number for all 5 or 50 users if they don't save the invoice object until later.

The `GetTheNextAvailableNumber()` method which called inside the `TransactionScope` block uses a Subsonic Select query with a `MAX()` to get the maximum number, then adds 1. The column itself does have a UNIQUE index!

Would the Transaction's **isolation level** default (Serializable) make sure that each of those gets a unique number? Or is there a more clever mechanism to achieve that?
The column cannot have an IDENTITY, since the PK column **InvoiceID** already has it.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about concurrency here over the span of a transaction - the only way this would work is to throw a lock on the table while the trannie executes and ... that can kill your app.

Is there a chance you can use a Guid?

Comment: Thanks Rob,
I was thinking about using a Guid as the table's primary key, however, for the invoice number I need a nicely formatted, readable number (int or bigint with leading zeroes, like 0000000191).
I suppose using a Guid as the PK will let me use the IDENTITY on the invoice numebr column... is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

What if you build a second table in your db and store value of the `NextAvailableNumber` in that table. Then you'd use a stored procedure to retrieve that value and increment it in the same call. You'd just need to lock that stored procedure to prevent concurrent calls. You also might be able to lock it within the stored procedure.